Calculating Amperage needed for Electroplating Copper
Im trying to determine what amperage is needed to plate 1oz copper with nickel.
So what i found from research is that you can use this formula: I=$\frac{Q}{t}$
and using Faraday's first law: $Q=\frac{m⋅F⋅z}{M}$
m≈28.35g (mass of the copper piece)
F≈96485 C/mol (Faraday's constant)
z=2 (valency of nickel)
M≈58.69 g/mol (molar mass of nickel)
$Q=\frac{28.35g⋅96485C/mol⋅2}{​58.68g/mol}$
Q≈ 93213.49C
To calculate current: I=$\frac{Q}{t}$
t=3000s (time in seconds)
I=$\frac{93213.49C}{3000s}$
I ≈ 31.07A
So it seems that i would need 31.07A to plate the copper. However i also found another formula to calculate the time needed/Amperage for a specific thickness of nickel plating: m=V⋅ρ
Thickness (t): 150 micrometers = 0.150 mm = 0.000150 m
Surface Area Copper (A): 0.0027935m²
Volume of Nickel (V): 0.00000125m³
Density of Nickel: Approximately 8.90 g/cm³ = 8900 kg/m³
M≈58.69 g/mol (molar mass of nickel)
t=3000s (time in seconds)
m=V⋅ρ
m=0.00000125m³⋅8900 kg/m³
m=0.011125kg = 11.125g
$Q=\frac{m⋅F⋅z}{M}$
$Q=\frac{11.125g⋅93213.49C⋅2}{58.69 g/mol}$
Q≈35338.22C
I=$\frac{Q}{t}$
​I=$\frac{35338.22C}{3000s}$
I≈11.78A
This seems to me to be a bit much amperage for as little as 1oz. As well as I have 2 different Amperage's for the same amount of time, which is a bit confusing.
I have also found this document: https://nickelinstitute.org/media/lxxh1zwr/2023-nickelplatinghandbooka5_printablepdf.pdf talking about electroplating where i have found the following table:
Table
I was wondering what they meant by Current Density since it seems much lower than the current needed.
Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!!

It is always good to describe the problem/task primarily with symbolic algebraic expressions . And it is good to keep it that way until all is ready to just plug-in literal numbers with explicit units. It helps in focusing on principles, mistakes are easier to spot, orientation is improved, Q/A is reusable and has bigger  permanent value.  //
You may find useful  formatting mathematical/chemical expressions/formulas.

m is not the mass of the copper piece but the final mass of nickel plating. // You erroneously use F= 93213 C/mol.

The needed time should be a result, not a starting point.
